# Hinge Joint making rope

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I've entered unity3d programming a few months ago. I've been clear some project with unity3d easily. In recent my project I have to make a rope like chain.

I read some articles and make it with Hinge Joint.

Problem: Smaller count of joints it works well. But if it over one hundreds of joint, it loses it's safety.

Progress: So I have been looking for solve this problem, but I can't find its perfect solution.

How can do this? How can I solve this problem. thank you for read my article.

Comment: How many elements does your chain contain? Is there a rigged model underlying?

Comment: 50 elements Ok, But over 100 elements it work hard.

Comment: When you say "work hard" and "loses its safety," what do you mean?  Do you mean it doesn't work, or that it work but doesn't perform, or both?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/304886/problem-with-hinge-joint-making-rope.html.

Comment: Look Here. I attached my file in answers.unity3d.com:   http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/304886/problem-with-hinge-joint-making-rope.html

Comment: According to [How do I create a chain using joints and rigidbodies?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22159/how-do-i-create-a-chain-using-joints-and-rigidbodi.html) the hinge joint might not be the best solution compared to a configurable joint.

Comment: Thank you Kay. I have look this article and I tried it. But elements(joints) are falling down. what does it matter.