# Unity3d swing ball like pendulum

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello every unity programmers and stackoverflow members. I'm progressing past article's [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038207/hinge-joint-making-rope)

I have no solution before article. So I changed to other method.

I want a animation like pendulum moves. I make 2 object A and B;

A:  Added rigidbody component setted with IsKinematic.

B:  Add rigidbody component setted default;   and add Hinge Joint and set connected body to Object A. and have suitable offset with A.

And when I play this, it(Obj B) has no action. To give movement I move B object in Scene mode,  But B goes it's position.

Why? How Can I Solve this Problem. I want animate the Ball B like pendulum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the hinge joint to object A not B (with isKinematic set to true) and set the axis you want

attach object B to the joint